# jQuery plugin practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I am working on a jQuery plugin and I would like some opinions from more experienced people about good practices of integrating the HTML, CSS and JavaScript code.

Specifically:

1.HTML code - static vs dynamic

Is it good to write only the bare minimum of HTML markup and dynamically create the rest of the needed HTML code through JavaScript, in the plugin ?

Or is it better to just manually write all of the needed HTML ?

Only the minimum HTML looks cleaner and easier to modify, all of the required HTML might be better to fully understand, customize and work with the plugin, as you see the entire structure of the code.

2.CSS code - in JavaScript or external

Is it good to create and apply the CSS code dynamically, in JavaScript, or have the CSS code external, in a CSS file ?

If the CSS is internal, it is dynamically created based on the specified properties of the plugin. There will be more properties, but all of the settings are specified in one place, in the settings of the plugin.

If the code is external, the user needs to edit the CSS in order to modify the different options available.

On the one side, having minimal HTML and dynamically created CSS seems easier for the user to understand, on the other, having all the HTML and external CSS seems more powerful and better for more advanced plugins.

What I am looking for are some pointers from experienced users on good practices about integrating the HTML, CSS and JavaScript in creating a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Is it good to write only the bare minimum of HTML markup and dynamically create the rest of the needed HTML code through JavaScript, in the plugin ?

Yes, this is how jQuery UI plugin(and most other plugin) works.

> 2.CSS code - in JavaScript or external?

It depends how much the css rules are complicated, in jQuery UI they use a css file, in jQuery Validation they don't.

Comment: Here are my thoughts regarding the CSS: 1. for a smaller plugin, I can use the plugin options to specify all of the needed settings so that the user can control everything from one place and so that he doesn't need to worry about editing the external CSS. But this option does not look as good for a larger plugin that may have a lot of options. 2. If I create the CSS dynamically, I create only the CSS that I need for the current state of the plugin. In the case that I create an external CSS, there is the possibility that I unused code such as having styles not applicable for my current state.

Comment: One question regarding your answer to point number 1: If the HTML is built through JavaScript, the page will have to wait until all of the JS resources are loaded and only then display the code. Won't it be better if the code already existed on the page and was styled as soon as the CSS was loaded ?

Comment: @IulianStanescu. if it's small DOM manipulation, it's so quick that it doesn't matter. If it has thousands  of iterations, then it might worth do it in the HTML. But if that's the case, you have a wired plugin and you'll face other problems soon... :)

Answer (score 0):

1. That largely depends on what your plugin is going to do. If JavaScript isn't present and the elements have no other function without JavaScript them I would create those elements with JavaScript.
2. Always, always, always keep your CSS in CSS files. Simply use jQuery to add classes.

Put yourself in the shoes of the developer who wants to use your code but doesn't want to have to edit the JS plugin every time they want to customize it.

As a general rule of thumb, any HTML you create with a jQuery plugin should be customizable by changing the default parameters of the plugin.

Comment: My initial idea was for all of the settings to be controlled from the plugin settings, thus having all of the necessary customization options in one place, rather than having some options here and having to edit the CSS file for others (applicable in my not so big plugin). But this option does not seem as good for bigger plugins where there would potentially be a lot of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Depend if you want good performance and create plug-in for one or some particular projects then you can follow rule below:**

You should have to put CSS in same Style Sheet you using already. If you want to make it easy to modify in future you can separate it by comments.

Also You have to define HTML tag already in HTML. If you can(If it's not dynamic or depend on condition) so that you can just target it and do whatever you want to do with it.

If you do have any conditional HTML then you can create it in JavaScript in a separate view section. So that anyone can find almost all tags together if he/she want to edit it in future.

**If you want plug-in for everyone can use it in any project. Then you have to make little bit compromise by performance. You should have to place HTML and CSS different from your project So that it can assemble easily by adding reference to one or two files (Not need to copy and paste code from different places).**

Then you should have to create different Style Sheets for your CSS if you do have lots of CSS otherwise define it in JavaScript.

You should have to create HTML in JavaScript and try to put it together as a view. So that it can easily edit in future.